# Assigned object value changed when assigning it to another object variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically what i'm trying to do is resetting the player stats using a stored default value. The thing is when the player revived and its stats restored, the default stats ended up changing when i did not change its value.

I've tried to use copy constructor and to set each variable individually and it works. Some how just setting it directly ended up with having that bug.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

/*
 *      things to do:
 *      1. respawn point
 *      2. fix this strange bug
 */
namespace Outbreak
{
    public class LivingEntity : MonoBehaviour, IDamageable
    {
        public Stats defaultStats;
        public event System.Action OnDeath;


        protected Stats stats;
        public Stats Stats
        {
            get
            {
                return stats;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Awake()
        {
            stats = new Stats(defaultStats);
        }

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        protected virtual void Start()
        {

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        protected virtual void Update()
        {

        }

        public void TakeDamage(float damage)
        {
            Debug.Log(defaultStats.IsDead);

            //if not dead
            if (stats.IsDead == false)
            {
                //and it still has health left
                if (stats.Health > 0)
                {
                    //take damage
                    stats.Health -= damage; 
                }
                //after taking damage check if health is depleted.
                if (stats.Health <= 0)
                {
                    //pronouce it dead
                    Die();
                }
            }

        }

        protected virtual void Die()
        {
            //set its status to dead
            stats.IsDead = true;

            //broadcast to all listener that this player is dead
            if (OnDeath != null)
            {
                OnDeath();
            }

            //make player invisible
            gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            //prevent any collision
            gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().enabled = false;
            //prevent player detecting collision
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().detectCollisions = false;
            //set to kinematic
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        }

        protected IEnumerator DelayedRevival()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.0f);
            Revive();
            yield return null;
        }

        protected virtual void Revive()
        {
            //2.  reset to default stats
            //stats = new Stats(defaultStats);
            //stats.IsDead = false;
            //stats.Health = 3;
            //stats.MovementSpeed = 10;
            stats = defaultStats;

            //1. set position to last respawn point location
            transform.position = Vector3.zero + (Vector3.up * 1.5f);

            //make player visible
            gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
            //allow for collision
            gameObject.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().enabled = true;
            //allow player to detect collision
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().detectCollisions = true;
            //set to dynamic
            gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Outbreak
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController), typeof(CharacterInput))]
    public class Character : LivingEntity
    {

        protected override void Awake()
        {
            base.Awake();

        }
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        protected override void Start()
        {
            base.Start();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        protected override void Update()
        {
            base.Update();
        }

        protected override void Die()
        {
            base.Die();
            gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterInput>().enabled = false;
            gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = false;
            StartCoroutine(DelayedRevival());
        }

        protected override void Revive()
        {
            base.Revive();
            gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterInput>().enabled = true;
            gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Outbreak
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Stats
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private float health;
        [SerializeField]
        private float movementSpeed;
        [SerializeField]
        private bool isDead;

        public Stats()
        {
            health = 3.0f;
            movementSpeed = 5.0f;
            isDead = false;
        }

        public Stats(Stats stats)
        {
            health = stats.health;
            movementSpeed = stats.movementSpeed;
            isDead = stats.isDead;
        }

        public float Health
        {
            set
            {
                health = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return health;
            }
        }

        public float MovementSpeed
        {
            set
            {
                movementSpeed = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return movementSpeed;
            }
        }

        public bool IsDead
        {
            set
            {
                isDead = value;
            }
            get
            {
                return isDead;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that the default value should not be change but the actual result ended up with the default value changing.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are assigning an initial value to the default Stats anywhere.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield its in the revive function in the LivingEntity class.

Comment: No it isn't. There is no assignment of any of the values of the `defaultStats` field in that method, or anywhere else that I can see. In the `revive` method, you assign the `stats` field to the value of the `defaultStats` field.

Comment: Just in general you should limit all those `GetComponent` calls to the `Awake` method and then reuse the references.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield it is `public` and `Serializable` so OP configures the default values using the Unity Inspector. Otherwise he would already get some `NullReferenceException` in `Awake` ;)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Sorry for the late reply. umm, I've ended up misreading your question... What derHugo said was right, I configured the default value using the inspector, so it ended up looking like i didn't assign an initial value anywhere.

Comment: Just remember to put information like that in your question next time.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Yeah, i will do that next time. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem line is

```
stats = defaultStats;
```

Since the type `Stats` is a **reference-type** not a value-type this assignment makes `stats` have the same **reference** as `defaultStats` => they point now to one and the same object.

Any future changes you make to one of them is done to one and the same referenced `Stats` object.

---

You should either make your assignment like you did in `Awake`:

```
 stats = new Stats(defaultStats);
```

which copies the values instead.

Or alternatively you could make your `Stats` not a `class` but a `struct` instead which converts it to a value-type

```
[Serializable]
public struct Stats
{
    ...
}
```

---

Hint: As said in the comments you should make all `GetComponent` calls only once in e.g. `Awake` and later reuse the stores references like

```
private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
private CapsuleCollider capsuleCollider;
private Rigidbody rigidBody;

private void Awake()
{
    meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    capsuleCollider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
    rigidBody = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
}
```

than later you reuse those stored references e.g.

```
meshRenderer.enabled = false;
capsuleCollider.enabled = false;
rigidBody.detectCollisions = false;
rigidBody.isKinematic = true;
```

And in `Character` you do the same with `CharacterInput` and `CharacterController`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now I understand what's going on. As for the `GetComponent` thing, well... i was thinking of a way to properly handle player death and revival. Setting a gameobject inactive was a no go since i am using events and `IEnumerator` functions with `yield` statements in it, as the code will break. So, I wasn't thinking of properly optimizing stuff.